# Cannot login using H2 database accessed through Hikari

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, hikaricp

SOLVED: I debugged for a long time to solve a problem with Spring, Hikari and H2. This post is to share my solution. No more help is needed.

I had a Spring Boot application with standard form login. The username/password data was in a H2 database accessed through Hikari. I was able to view and edit my data in the H2 console, but login did not work even when I provided the right credentials.

I was running my application as a stand-alone jar. When I restarted my application, I still had old data in my H2 database, even though this data should be removed by Spring.

Here is the main class:

```
package com.github.mhdirkse.timewriter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TimeWriterApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TimeWriterApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

Here is my applications.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

# Datasource
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:h2:file:~/test2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

logging.level.com.github.mhdirkse.=DEBUG
```

And here is my UserDetailsServiceImpl():

```
package com.github.mhdirkse.timewriter;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import com.github.mhdirkse.timewriter.model.UserInfo;

public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserInfoRepository userInfoRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        logger.debug(String.format("Login requested with username %s", username));
        UserInfo user = userInfoRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null) {
            logger.debug("User not found in database");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        logger.debug("Obtained user %s from database.", user.getUsername());
        return new UserPrincipal(user);
    }

}
```

The following console output was produced:

```
2018-10-17 18:41:52.026 DEBUG 10152 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.g.m.timewriter.UserDetailsServiceImpl  : Login requested with username mhdirkse
2018-10-17 18:41:52.186  INFO 10152 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2018-10-17 18:41:53.261 DEBUG 10152 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.g.m.timewriter.UserDetailsServiceImpl  : User not found in database
2018-10-17 18:43:35.546 DEBUG 10152 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.g.m.timewriter.UserDetailsServiceImpl  : Login requested with username mhdirkse
2018-10-17 18:43:35.555 DEBUG 10152 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.g.m.timewriter.UserDetailsServiceImpl  : User not found in database
```

I also ran my application with more debug logging to see the SQL query that was applied during login. I copied that query to the H2 console and there it produced my login credentials.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in application.properties. Replace property name `spring.datasource.jdbcUrl` by just `spring.datasource.url`. Then application.properties becomes:

```
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

logging.level.com.github.mhdirkse.=DEBUG
```

The property `spring.datasource.jdbcUrl` is defined by Hikari, while `spring.datasource.url` is defined by Spring or Spring Boot.

With kind regards,

Martijn Dirkse